# marked for deletion message in broker kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, kafka-topic

why when deleting one topic in Kafka by this command :

```
/opt/kafka/confluent-4.0.0/bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper 109.169.xxx.xx:2181  --delete --topic test
```

and again see the list of Topics again, This message appears?

```
test - marked for deletion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If after a long time your topic is not deleted then make sure that `delete.topic.enable` in `server.properties` is set to `true` (although confluent 4.0.0 comes with this configuration). If you still face the same issue you can manually delete the topic by logging into Zookeeper using

```
zookeeper-shell localhost:2181
```

Now you can remove the topic using

```
rmr /brokers/topics/{topic_name}
rmr /admin/delete_topics/{topic_name}
```

Note that you might need to delete topic folder from Kafka broker machine before logging into ZK in order to manually remove the topic.

Answer (score 2):

In Kafka, topic deletion is asynchronous. When you run the `kafka-topics` tool with `--delete`, you are simply marking the topic for deletion.

The actual deletion happens in most cases shortly after but depending on the state of your cluster it can be delayed.

In case it gets stuck, bouncing the controller usually helps.

Comment: What does "bouncing the controller" means?

Comment: Bouncing means restarting. When it comes to the controller, you can often just re-elect a new controller by deleting the /controller node in Zookeeper instead of restarting the broker.